# Duplicate Tooltip style and size for custom draw

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I created my custom Tooltip, but what I need is that it will be with the same style as system draws it when you do not switch on the OwnerDraw flag.
How can I create custom tooltip which looks exactly like the "original" one?

```
ttSessionInfo.ToolTipTitle = UiTranslator.Instance.GetLabel(UiLabels.DC_DSE_Session);

var toolTipSessionsText = sessions.Aggregate(
                        new StringBuilder(),
                        (p_strBuilder, p_session) => p_strBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", p_session.SessionName,
                            p_session.IsConnected ? connectedText : disconnectedText))).ToString();

ttSessionInfo.SetToolTip(LiveUpdatePb, toolTipSessionsText);
```

Result is:

[image: This looks like]

I need the same tooltip exactly to show on another control, but to paint ,lets say, the second row "Alex Session: Connected" with red color.

Comment: It's better to show what you have done. some sample codes ...

Comment: @saeed I've updated my question. I want same functionality(as system default), but with ability to paint my text whereever I want.

Comment: what is base class of ttSessionInfo

Comment: private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ttSessionInfo;

Comment: have you tried to re-implement tooltip class for **OnDraw** function.

Comment: @saeed No. Is this the only one option? If yes, do you have any piece of example code? Thanks

Comment: I will add a sample in answers but there may be some other solutions so.

Comment: If my answer was not useful to you tell me to delete it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I added a sample that re-implements ToolTip class and codes to use it.

class:

```
class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
    {
        public CustomToolTip()
        {
            this.OwnerDraw = true;
            this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
            this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
        }

        string m_EndSpecialText;
        Color m_EndSpecialTextColor =Color.Red;

        public Color EndSpecialTextColor
        {
            get { return m_EndSpecialTextColor; }
            set { m_EndSpecialTextColor = value; }
        }

        public string EndSpecialText
        {
            get { return m_EndSpecialText; }
            set { m_EndSpecialText = value; }
        }

        private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e) // use this event to set the size of the tool tip
        {
            e.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 100);
        }

        private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e) // use this event to customise the tool tip
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds,
                Color.GreenYellow, Color.MintCream, 45f);

            g.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);

            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
                e.Bounds.Width - 1, e.Bounds.Height - 1));

            //g.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Silver,
            //    new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 6, e.Bounds.Y + 6)); // shadow layer
            g.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black,
                new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + 5)); // top layer

            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(EndSpecialTextColor);

            g.DrawString(EndSpecialText, new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold), brush,
                new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Bottom - 15)); // top layer

            brush.Dispose();
            b.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

following the use of above class

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomToolTip toolTip1 = new CustomToolTip();
        toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Click me to execute.");
        toolTip1.EndSpecialText = "Hello I am special";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @Geka P was this post useful to you if not let me to delete it.

Comment: This works, solves the OP's problem, and should be marked as the answer.